# Swapping start and end points of line (i.e. direction) of LineString in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, linestring

I know that postgis has the function to find the start and end point of a line.
Is there a function that can swap the start point and end point?

(Note: I do not mean literally changing the co-ordinates).

You could also describe it as switching direction of a linestring.

Or in technical terms I think we just have to reverse the sequence of coordinates.

I know a [gis tool](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DigitizingTools/) which does this, but is there postgis counterpart?

Comment: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Reverse.html. Generally http://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html is a good reference.

Comment: The operation has traditionally been called "Flip", since a "swap" of start/end points on a complex polyline would be disastrous.